# Calculating the monthly total on every row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am looking for the right formula to identify the month in the date (column A) on each row and then spit out the "current month's total" (column C) into each row in column D. Once it reaches the end of the month, it should start over.

I found the SUMPRODUCT function to come close, but it doesn't seem to copy the function correctly after dragging the corner down in automation.

Here is what I currently have: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A5000)=MONTH(A2))*(YEAR(A2:A5000)=YEAR(A2))*C2:C5000)`

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

[image: Excel Monthly Totals]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things with your formula:

- Ypou need to anchor you Date and Value ranges, using `$`
- You need to add a condition to only sum down to the current row

Try this for Cell `D2` and copy down

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A$2:A$5000)=MONTH(A2))*(YEAR(A$2:A$5000)=YEAR(A2))*(ROW(A$2:A$5000)<=ROW())*C$2:C$5000)
```

Comment: Sorry @Chris, but why are you using `(ROW(A$2:A$5000)<=ROW())` if you could use `A$2:A2` instead : `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A$2:A2)=MONTH(A2))*(YEAR(A$2:A2)=YEAR(A2))*C$2:C2)`?

Comment: @simoco either works, neither has a major advantage over the other.  I just just find the partialy anchored range slightly inconvenient